# Moving Wordpress siteurl and home setting from database to wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way I can move my Wordpress domain configuration settings:

- siteurl
- home

from the database wp-options table to wp-config.php?

I want to be able to sync my live DB with my localhost at times for development purposes, but it's annoying having to change these settings in the database each time.

I'm using git, and have a wp-config.production.php, and wp-config.testing.php in my repository, which is symlinked with Capistrano upon deployment, so ideally I want to add my domain settings to these files respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, seems to work okay:

Add the following to wp-config.php

```
/** Domain settings (No trailing slash!)*/
define ('SITEURL', 'http://domain.dev');
define ('HOME', 'http://domain.dev');
```

Then in function.php add:

```
<?php

update_domain_settings();

/**
 * update_domain_settings
 */
function update_domain_settings()
{
    $domain_updated = false;

    if(get_option('siteurl') != SITEURL) {
        update_option('siteurl', SITEURL);
        $domain_updated = true;
    }

    if(get_option('home') != HOME) {
        update_option('home', HOME);
        $domain_updated = true;
    }

    if($domain_updated === true) {
        header("Location: " . home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

It's important to omit the trailing slash in the SITEURL and HOME otherwise you'll end up with a recursive redirection problem.